# Sending updates only to specific users on Android

Tags: android

Suppose as an app developer, I want to send app updates only to some of my users. Is there a way to do that via Google Play, Google Cloud Messaging or some third-party app stores etc? How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

you could use [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) for this purpose. Also you will need some database (own backend or firebase DB) where you will store the IDs of your users, that you receive with

> FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()

With ID you can identify your users (extra values, that you will send with this ID to your backend) to that you would send some updates.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the beta program where certain users can be added.